# How can I tell Apple iCloud to forget or delete system configuration settings?

Tags: macos, icloud

I've noticed that whenever I setup a new iMac or MacBook, that small system configurations from older/other systems are copied over to my new system as soon as I login to iCloud.  While I like iCloud for syncing files across desktops, I don't necessarily want each of my systems to share the same configurations.  It's a granular as the speed of my pointer or the touch settings on the trackpad.  With a couple iMac's and a physically different layout in my offices, this shared configuration is obtrusive and I frequently need to revise it.  Is there a way to enjoy some iCloud features on one Apple ID account, but not have every system configuration shared?

I've noticed other settings sync in the past, but "Tap to click" and "Tracking speed" are the most annoying.  On one of my physical desks, I've my trackpad off to the side like "normal" people :P. At my other office, I've the trackpad and keyboard in a container laid out like a MacBook so bumping it with my palm causes a tap-to-click, so I have to turn it off. If I turn it back on on the other system, it updates both.

[image]

Comment: Fascinating. My several systems on two different accounts do not sync any settings - just files and purchase history. Do you want to edit a screen shot or one specific setting and I’ll test that one to be sure you have a good answer

Answer (score 1):

**iCloud does not sync settings like mouse pointer speed.** If these settings are appearing on a new system, it means you have implemented an alternative syncing method (inadvertently or not).

Comment: Interesting.  I don't know of any alternative syncing methods.  Perhaps I'm misinterpreting what is happening.  Maybe the systems are reverting or losing configurations when I apply system updates.  I usually, eventually just enable auto updates, so if that is happening it might give the illusion that configurations are synchronizing when they are simply reverting back to defaults.  I'll have to make note and watch it more closely.  Thank you.